# Lipo error with additional schemes in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, lipo

I want to create additional build configurations and schemes in my Xcode project in order to build specific archives for TestFlight. One connected to our DEV environment for internal testers, and one connected to our PROD environment for external beta testers.

So I was following [this excellent blog](http://stablekernel.com/blog/ios-build-configurations-and-schemes/) post and I created 2 additional build configurations by duplicating the Release one. Then I created 2 additional schemes based on the default one, by changing the build configuration of the Archive build operation to the proper build configuration. Finally I set some user-defined settings in each build configuration to point to the right server URL depending on whether we are in a DEV build or a PROD build.

But now when I archive my project using one of these two additional schemes, I get the following Lipo error:

> /fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can’t open input file: /Users/sarbogast/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyAppTestFlightPROD/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyApp.build/TestFlight PROD-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyApp (No such file or directory)

And indeed when I go to `/Users/sarbogast/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyAppTestFlightPROD/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyApp.build/TestFlight PROD-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7` directory, there is no MyApp file or directory in there.

I read here and there that setting 'Build Active Architecture only' to YES might solve the problem, but I don't want to do that as these are release builds for TestFlight and I want them to work on all architectures.

What might be wrong in my set up?

Answer (score 0):

I am using CocoaPods and I had log messages saying that the linker could not find Pods for my new scheme. So I added my new scheme to link_with in my podfile and now it works perfectly.
I still don't understand why, because I thought link_with was only to list targets and this is not a target, this is a scheme. But it works.